# Random putting out higher numbers than it should

Tags: c++

Hi guys i have just started programming and and watching a 4 hour c++ course. I wanted to make my own little game. I've made a random and the random number is higher than told.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

class Player{
public:
    int health = 100;

    void setHealth(int hlth){
        health = hlth;
    }

    int getHealth(){
        return health;
    }

};

Player p;

class Enemy{
public:
    void attack(){
        srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) );
        int damage;
        int crit = rand() % 10 + 1;
        if(crit == 10){
            damage = 40;
        }else{
            damage = rand() % 30 + 10; // This random
        }
        int health = p.getHealth() - damage;
        p.setHealth(health);
        std::cout << "You are getting attacked by an enemy -" << damage << " health." << std::endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Enemy e;
    e.attack();
    std::cout << "You have " << p.getHealth() << " hp left"<< std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Sometimes the output is higher than 30 but the code is `damage = rand() % 30 + 10;`

I might have misunderstood something but i can't explain why this happens.

Solution: `rand() % (31 - 10) + 10;`

Comment: It's higher than 30 because you add 10 after taking the random value mod 30.

Comment: The range of values is 29 + 10. `rand()` is not the best random generator. The seed should be in main.

Comment: Since you're using C++ you have no reason to use `rand()`, it's trash. Use the [C++ Random Number facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) in the Standard Library. You want to use [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) to represent dice.

Comment: It's worth noting that `rand() % 10` does *not* produce even results. It's actually slightly biased since `MAX_RAND` is unlikely to be a multiple of 10.

Comment: Longer (and quite humorous) discussion of the points tadman raises above: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)